# How can you make your own authenticated REST requests?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm using `admin-on-rest` behind a login screen. I'm writing a custom form component. When I do a `fetch` call to the same server AOR is using, I get a 401. How can I use the same auth data that AOR is using with its requests?

Comment: Do you mean JSON server? That is a third party component and you should find what you need in its documentation. 

https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: How have you configured your auth client ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `fetch` call, include this second argument:

```
fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
```

otherwise the auth cookie isn't sent with the request.